# How to remove rows after the first occurrence when the following row matches

Tags: r

Working in R I am trying to remove all rows following a change. A business is open for 3 years then closes, the closed flag stays in the table for the following years. I want to remove the 2 extra years keeping only the data for the year it closed. Some locations close and reopen in the same year they should not be changed.

I've tried slice on min date when `status = "close"` but this will not work because of the locations that reopen.

Sample data

```
date <- c("2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2016","2017","2018","2019","2015","2016","2017","2018","2018","2019","2019")
ID <- c("1","1","1","1","1", "1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3", "3")
status <- c("open", "open", "open", "close", "close", "close", "open", "open","open","open","open", "open", "open","close", "open", "close", "open")


start <- data.frame(date, ID, status)
```

Above I want to remove the 2018 and 2019 for ID = 1

```r
date <- c("2014","2015","2016","2017","2016","2017","2018","2019","2015","2016","2017","2018","2018","2019","2019")
ID <- c("1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3","3","3","3", "3")
status <- c("open", "open", "open", "close", "open", "open","open","open","open", "open", "open","close", "open", "close", "open")


ideal_outcome <- data.frame(date, ID, status)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `rleid` from `data.table` is to `group_by` `ID` and consecutive runs of `status`, keep only one row for the group where `status = "close"` and select all rows for `"open"`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

start %>%
  group_by(ID, group = rleid(status)) %>%
  slice(if (first(status) == "open") seq_len(n()) else  1L) %>%
  mutate(status = replace(as.character(status), 
                    status == "close", "permanently_closed")) %>%  
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)

# A tibble: 15 x 3
#   date  ID    status
#   <fct> <fct> <chr> 
# 1 2014  1     open  
# 2 2015  1     open  
# 3 2016  1     open  
# 4 2017  1     permanently_closed 
# 5 2016  2     open  
# 6 2017  2     open  
# 7 2018  2     open  
# 8 2019  2     open  
# 9 2015  3     open  
#10 2016  3     open  
#11 2017  3     open  
#12 2018  3     permanently_closed 
#13 2018  3     open  
#14 2019  3     permanently_closed 
#15 2019  3     open
```

However, you don't really need to import `data.table` just for one function, behaviour of `rleid` can be replicated with base `rle` as well

```
start %>%
  group_by(ID, group = with(rle(as.character(status)), 
                       rep(seq_along(values), lengths))) %>%
   slice(if (first(status) == "open") seq_len(n()) else  1L) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(-group)
```

---

Another way to create groups as suggested by @Sotos using `factor`, `diff` and `cumsum`

```
start %>% 
  group_by(grp = as.numeric(as.factor(status)), 
           grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(grp) != 0))) %>%
  slice(if (first(status) == "open") seq_len(n()) else  1L)
```

Comment: or create `as.numeric(as.factor(...))` and play with `diff` and `cumsum` :) Nice ans btw

Comment: @Sotos but won't `as.numeric(as.factor(` give same numbers to all "open" and "close" values ? We want to know when they open and close as well? Maybe I am missing your approach then?

Comment: Thank you but for future can you tell me how this works? seq_len(n()) else  1L

Comment: Try this `start %>% mutate(grp = as.numeric(as.factor(status)), grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(grp) != 0)))`

Comment: @Jeffkrop so basically it makes sure that whenever there is consecutive "close" it will only select one of them.

Comment: @Sotos Ahh...I see what you mean now and then use the same `slice` method. Nice. :)

Comment: Can the status be changed from "close" to "permanently_closed" on these rows?